# How to Get the selected item in a recyclerview, when is within a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

From the current fragment, I want to get the position of the selected item in recyclerview, but not in the adapter

now I have two recyclerview.
Clicking one I want to send my data to the second, but by the current fragment, because this will generate adional data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved.
first of all it is important to create an interface that contains a function and overrrite this function in the class fragment.

Exemple

Cintasadapter [adapter]
Cargas_detalle_previo [fragment]

create an interface in adapter for exemple
EXEMPLE
**CintasAdapter.java**

```
 /// The interface
public interface getselectpos
    {
        void onItemClick(CintasHolder holder, int posicion);
    }

private getselectpos interfaceclick;
//Declared a private variable to manage the interface



//in the constructor recover the interface, for exemple.

//CintasDataset is a class to manage the data for the adapter

 public CintasAdapter(List<CintasDataset> items, getselectpos Interfaceclick)
    {
        this.mitems = items; //the elements 
        this.interfaceclick=Interfaceclick; // the interface create from in the fragment
    }




/// Class holder for this class , and implements OnClickListener

public class CintasHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        public ImageView imagen; //an imagen
        public TextView modocorte;/a textview 

        public CintasHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);//add the listener for an element
        }

        //add onClick and set the funcion onItemClick , declared in the interface
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            interfaceclick.onItemClick(this, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
```

Implements that interface in the fragment

EXEMPLE
**Cargas_detalle_previo.java**

```
//Cargas_detalle_previo is the fragment class, the interface  "CintasAdapter.getselectpos "
public class Cargas_detalle_previo extends Fragment  implements  CintasAdapter.getselectpos
{
    //TODO CONTENT
    //exemple for onViewCreated
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //TODO CONTENT
         List mitems2 = new ArrayList(); // for exemple 

        //declared the adapter
         final CintasAdapter adaptercintas = new CintasAdapter(mitems,this);
    }



    //and  override the function in the interface, in the case  onItemClick
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(CintasAdapter.CintasHolder holder, int posicion)
    {


        //and use the posicion 

        //exemple to show the posicion
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),posicion+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

}
```

- https://dzone.com/articles/programming-when-use
- http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/java-interface/

**And sorry for my bad english**

*I resolved this by a friend told me to check interfaces in java, I hope it can serve someone else*